# Fastest way to delete the first few bytes of a file

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5

I am using a windows mobile compact edition 6.5 phone and am writing out binary data to a file from bluetooth.  These files get quite large, 16M+ and what I need to do is to once the file is written then I need to search the file for a start character and then delete everything before, thus eliminating garbage.  I cannot do this inline when the data comes in due to graphing issues and speed as I get alot of data coming in and there is already too many if conditions on the incoming data.  I figured it was best to post process.  Anyway here is my dilemma, speed of search for the start bytes and the rewrite of the file takes sometimes 5mins or more...I basically move the file over to a temp file parse through it and rewrite a whole new file.  I have to do this byte by byte.

```
private void closeFiles() {
    try {

    // Close file stream for raw data.
    if (this.fsRaw != null) {
        this.fsRaw.Flush();
        this.fsRaw.Close();

        // Move file, seek the first sync bytes, 
        // write to fsRaw stream with sync byte and rest of data after it
        File.Move(this.s_fileNameRaw, this.s_fileNameRaw + ".old");
        FileStream fsRaw_Copy = File.Open(this.s_fileNameRaw + ".old", FileMode.Open);
        this.fsRaw = File.Create(this.s_fileNameRaw);

        int x = 0;
        bool syncFound = false;

        // search for sync byte algorithm
        while (x != -1) {
            ... logic to search for sync byte
            if (x != -1 && syncFound) {
                this.fsPatientRaw.WriteByte((byte)x);
            }
        }

        this.fsRaw.Close();

        fsRaw_Copy.Close();
        File.Delete(this.s_fileNameRaw + ".old");
    }


    } catch(IOException e) {
        CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR,"Exception in writing: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

There has got to be a faster way than this!

------------Testing times using answer -------------

Initial Test my way with one byte read and and one byte write:

```
27 Kb/sec
```

using a answer below and a 32768 byte buffer:

```
321 Kb/sec
```

using a answer below and a 65536 byte buffer:

```
501 Kb/sec
```

Comment: Untested, but I've heard the following idiom a few times: Memory-map the file, use `memmove()`, and flush the changes, truncatingly.

Comment: @Kerek- can't be done in managed code and Phone 7 only supports managed code.

Comment: @ctacke managed code supports memory mapped files. -- See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netframework-4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a byte-wise copy of the entire file.  That can't be efficient for a load of reasons.  Search for the start offset (and end offset if you need both), then copy from one stream to another the entire contents between the two offsets (or the start offset and end of file).

**EDIT**

You don't have to read the entire contents to make the copy.  Something like this (untested, but you get the idea) would work.

```
private void CopyPartial(string sourceName, byte syncByte, string destName)
{
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(sourceName))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(input))
    using (var output = File.Create(destName))
    {
        var start = 0;
        // seek to sync byte
        while (reader.ReadByte() != syncByte)
        {
            start++;
        }

        var buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4k page - adjust as you see fit

        do
        {
            var actual = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Write(buffer, 0, actual);
        } while (reader.PeekChar() >= 0);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

I actually needed something similar to this today, so I decided to write it without the PeekChar() call. Here's the kernel of what I did - feel free to integrate it with the second `do...while` loop above.

```
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var total = 0;

            do
            {
                var actual = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, actual);
                total += actual;
            } while (total < reader.BaseStream.Length);
```

Comment: Except for the only two functions available in CF are Read(byte[] a,int offset, int len) and ReadByte().  so creating a byte array that is over 16M seems memory intensive on a phone.

Comment: I just verified it work with Phone 7 or CF 3.5 projects just fine.  MSDN Agrees that it's availableas well for [the Phone] and [plain CF 3.5] [1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf6bat53(v=VS.95).aspx [2]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf6bat53(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Well its not available in my framework 6.0 or 6.5 won't compile if I put it in (by the way Target Framework is greyed out so no .Net available).  Documentation must be wrong... not the first time I've seen that with MSDN.

Comment: We need clarification.  There is no "CF 6.0" or "CF 6.5".  THere was 1.0, 2.0 and 3.5 (with some SPs in there).  Which version are you targeting?  AS I said, I tested these both in Studio (08 for the CF, and 2010 for the Phone) and they compile fine.

Comment: @JPM: Just watch out for the last bufferful of data - it is unlikely to exactly fill your 4096 byte buffer, so you could end up with junk appended to your file if it's not handled correctly.

Comment: @Jason, which is why you write `actual` bytes, not `buffer.Length`.

Comment: @JPM: What do you mean by "keep changing"?  I've editied twice - both times to add code to further clarify the answer. I edited most recently because I added code that didn't use PeekChar since you seem to be having trouble using it. Again, I tested this on an actual device so PeekChar does exist in CF 3.5, but if you are possibly using something older or for some reason simply don't ant to use PeekChar, I updated my answer with a solution that doesn't use it.

Comment: Sorry my fault I meant Windows Mobile SDK 6.0 in that PeekChar does not exists.  But if you look my question is tagged with 6.0 or 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

Don't discount an approach because you're afraid it will be too slow. **Try it!** It'll only take 5-10 minutes to give it a try and may result in a much better solution.

If the detection process for the start of the data is not too complex/slow, then avoiding writing data until you hit the start may actually make the program skip past the junk data *more efficiently*.

How to do this:

- Use a simple bool to know whether or not you have detected the start of the data. If you are reading junk, then don't *waste time* writing it to the output, just scan it to detect the start of the data. Once you find the start, then stop scanning for the start and just copy the data to the output. Just copying the good data will incur no more than an `if (found)` check, which really won't make any noticeable difference to your performance.

You may find that in itself solves the problem. But you can optimise it if you need more performance:

- What can you do to minimise the work you do to detect the start of the data? Perhaps if you are looking for a complex sequence you only need to check for one particular byte value that starts the sequence, and it's only if you find that start byte that you need to do any more complex checking. There are some very simple but efficient string searching algorithms that may help in this sort of case too. Or perhaps you can allocate a buffer (e.g. 4kB) and gradually fill it with bytes from your incoming stream. When the buffer is filled, *then and only then* search for the end of the "junk" in your buffer. By batching the work you can make use of memory/cache coherence to make the processing considerably more efficient than it would be if you did the same work byte by byte.
- Do all the other "conditions on the incoming data" need to be continually checked? How can you minimise the amount of work you need to do but still achieve the required results? Perhaps some of the ideas above might help here too?
- Do you actually need to do any processing on the data while you are skipping junk? If not, then you can break the whole thing into two phases (skip junk, copy data), and skipping the junk won't cost you anything when it actually matters.

Comment: Jason - Your statement 'Just copying the good data will incur no more than an if (found) check,'  is valid for most cases except when that if condition actually does impact speed or if you are trying to optimize a thread.  I found this to be true when running a Bluetooth SPP thread to read data coming at a huge data rate and from this I was graphing to the screen and saving to file on a phone.  So any little if condition impacted the plotting.  But I agree if you can copy good data then do so...

Comment: @JPM: Testing a bool will only add a significant overhead if you are doing it many *thousands* of times. The trick is not to work out how do more work, but how to avoid doing unnecessary work to achieve the same ends. It really shouldn't be necessary to "check the bool" very frequently. Just look at the speed difference you have quoted between "read an write one byte at a time" and "read and write in 64kB chunks". That is simply because you do one read/write operation instead of 65536 individual operations, which removes a lot of unnecessary overhead (it eliminates 65535 function calls, etc).

Comment: If you give more details of how you detect the end of the junk data, then I'd be able to offer some more specific suggestions. But spending minutes post-processing a massive file to move all the data down a few bytes is a very string "code smell" - there must be a better way.